# Referencing Subfigures in Range with Comma and Hyphen

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subfloats

I have a figure with 6 `subfloat` figures.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig1}\label{fig1}} \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig2}\label{fig2}} \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig3}\label{fig3}} \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig4}\label{fig4}} \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig5}\label{fig5}} \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig6}\label{fig6}} \hfill
    \caption{Analysis of color variation}
    \label{fig_main}
\end{figure}
```

I am trying to reference subfigures in **figure caption** and in **text**. Currently, i am using `\ref` to reference figures. I need two styles of references, one separated by hyphen and one separated by comma.

I need the caption of the figure as: `Analysis of color variation. (a-c) represent color. (d-f) represent contrast, and (a-c) represent gamma.`

In text, I need to reference `...as shown in Fig. 12(a, d), (b, e) and (c, f) respectively... Fig. 13(a) shows...`

Any idea how to achieve this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post such fragments only. You may have a look into `cleveref` which will provide customized cross-referencing formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{subfigure}{#2\onlyletter{#1}#3}
\crefrangeformat{subfigure}{(#3\onlyletter{#1}#4--#5\onlyletter{#2}#6)}
\crefmultiformat{subfigure}
  {(#2\onlyletter{#1}#3}
  {,~#2\onlyletter{#1}#3)}
  {,~#2\onlyletter{#1}#3)}
  {,~#2\onlyletter{#1}#3)}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\onlyletter}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_item:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { -1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{{\Huge #1}} % just for the example

\begin{document}

As shown in \cref{fig_main} \cref{fig1,fig4}, \cref{fig2,fig5}, and
\cref{fig3,fig6} respectively.

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig1}\label{fig1}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig2}\label{fig2}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig3}\label{fig3}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig4}\label{fig4}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig5}\label{fig5}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics{fig6}\label{fig6}}
\caption[Analysis of color variation]{%
  Analysis of color variation;
  \cref{fig1,fig2,fig3} represent color,
  \cref{fig4,fig5,fig6} represent contrast,
  and \cref{fig1,fig2,fig3} represent gamma.%
}
\label{fig_main}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The command `\includegraphics` has been given a suitable definition to emulate printing figures I don't have; you'll remove this definition and use `graphicx`, of course.

The main problem is to get subfigures referenced only with the letter, which requires the `\onlyletter` trick. The rest is standard `cleveref`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg, you saved the day. It works like a charm... Thanks dearie :)

Comment: +1. The `\onlyletter` trick is really neat. The same result could have been achieved, arguably somewhat more simply, by running `\makeatletter \renewcommand\p@subfigure{} \makeatother`, i.e., by un-setting the definition of `\p@subfigure`. Of course, the `cleveref`-related setup would still be needed.

Comment: @Mico You're right, but perhaps the whole reference is needed in other situations

Comment: @egreg exactly, that was the case. I had too many whole references besides this in the text.