# How to remove label and number from cref?

Tags: captions, subcaption, cleveref, subfig

I am trying to reference multiple subfigures in the caption of a figure separated by dash.
For example, the caption of the figure should look like:

> Fig1. this is a figure. (a) first figure. (b) second figure. (c-e) the
> rest of figures.

When I try using `\labelcref` the figure number still appears:

> Fig1. this is a figure. (a) first figure. (b) second figure. 1(c) to 1(e) the
> rest of figures.

how can I remove the number and label and just keep the letters?

The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407765/207525) did not work for me because of multiple **unrecogniazed command** errors, and it is too complicated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \setcounter{subfigure}{0}
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{fig1}\label{fig1}}
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{fig2}\label{fig2}}
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{fig3}\label{fig3}}
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{fig4}\label{fig4}}
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics{fig5}\label{fig5}}
        \caption{
            This is a figure.
            \cref{fig1} first figure,
            \cref{fig2} second figure,
            and \labelcref{fig3,fig4,fig5} rest of figures.
        }   
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the output I am getting:
[image]

But I want it to look like:

> Fig1. this is a figure. (a) first figure. (b) second figure. (c-e) the
> rest of figures.

Comment: As always ion this site: please provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as it. Then it is a lot easier to know exactly what you are doing and give advice based on that

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I added the code.

Comment: Note this is not self contained as we don't have the images. You either use say `\rule{3cm}{3cm}` or one of the images from the `mwe` pacjage. Also shouldn't the `\label` be placed in the `[]` argument for `\subfigure`?

Comment: You might want to use something else than `subfigure` as it has not been updated since 2005! and is considered obsolete (as is `epsfig`). Instead of `subfigure` the normal recommendation these days is probably the `subcaption` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, package `subcaption` is loaded instead of `subfigure`, and `epsfig` is replaced with `graphicx`. Recent version of `graphicx` can handle eps figures automatically. Also,

- `\subfloat` is used instead of `\subfigure` since `subcaption` defines the latter as an environment,
- option `labelsep=none` is used to center the caption of subfigure (since it has empty caption title), and
- option `subrefformat=parens` is used to make `\subref{fig1}` produce `(a)` instead of just `a`.

At last, dummy images provided by `mwe` package are used since I don't have image files `fig1`, `fig1`, ... .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\captionsetup[sub]{labelsep=none, subrefformat=parens}
\crefrangelabelformat{subfigure}
  {(#3\crefstripprefix{#2}{#1}#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6)}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[\label{fig1}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\quad
    \subfloat[\label{fig2}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}\quad
    \subfloat[\label{fig3}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}\\
    \subfloat[\label{fig4}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\quad
    \subfloat[\label{fig5}]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{%
        This is a figure.
        \subref{fig1} first figure,
        \subref{fig2} second figure,
        and \labelcref{fig3,fig4,fig5} rest of figures.
    }   
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer `\labelcref` from `cleveref` than `\subref` from `subcaption`, see answers in question [Combining cleveref and subref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333223/79060).